# Jquery validate within chrome extension options page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Completely new to this and JavaScript and coding in general so my apologies go out before I start.

I've been trying to use `jquery.validate.min.js` to check text inputs for a chrome extension's Options page I've been trying to create.

Things just go sideways when I add `<form>` tag to the options.html page: as soon as you click save button all the `options_ui.chrome_style` formatting is lost.

I've used chrome extension [options example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2) and get the same results.

mainfest.json

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "Options Test extension",
 "version": "1.0",

 "options_ui": {
  "page": "options.html",
  "chrome_style": true
 }
}
```

options.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>My Test Extension Options</title>
  <style>
   body: { padding: 10px; }
  </style>
 </head>

<body>
 <form id="form_a">
   Favorite color:
    <select id="color">
    <option value="red">red</option>
       <option value="green">green</option>
       <option value="blue">blue</option>
       <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
    </select>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="like">
        I like colors.
    </label>

    <div id="status"></div>
      <button id="save">Save</button>
   </form>
   <script src="options.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

options.js

```
 // Saves options to chrome.storage.sync.
 function save_options() {
  var color = document.getElementById('color').value;
  var likesColor = document.getElementById('like').checked;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
   favoriteColor: color,
   likesColor: likesColor
 }, function() {
  // Update status to let user know options were saved.
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
  setTimeout(function() {
    status.textContent = '';
  }, 750);
 });
 }

 // Restores select box and checkbox state using the preferences
 // stored in chrome.storage.
 function restore_options() {
   // Use default value color = 'red' and likesColor = true.
   chrome.storage.sync.get({
     favoriteColor: 'red',
     likesColor: true
   }, function(items) {
     document.getElementById('color').value = items.favoriteColor;
     document.getElementById('like').checked = items.likesColor;
   });
 }
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
 document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',
     save_options);
```

How would I go about validating inputs when I can't use the `<form>`, for the text inputs I have in my own extension?

Comment: Please note: took me a while to get from "things go sideways" to the actual description of the problem; I now edited your question so it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean by "things go sideways" is likely the default behavior of [`<button>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

If such an element is inside a `<form>` element, the default is to behave like a submit button. That's not what you want: it reloads the page (which apparently has an added effect of not applying `chrome_style` as it's not explicitly loaded "as the options page").

Your problems can be fixed by specifying the button type:

```
<button type="button" id="save">Save</button>
```

Alternatively, you could call `preventDefault()` on the event object in `save_options` (if you added an event parameter). But specifying a button type is cleaner.

Comment: And there you have it. 
I am stupid. Thank you Xan :)

Comment: Nothing stupid about not knowing something. It becomes stupid when you stop trying to learn.

Comment: Appreciate that. At times like this, when you've been banging your head against a wall, self doubt is at a max. A little boost is what you need, your comment did that.