# Problems with accessing chrome.storage.local.set/get from options.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Following code gets called from my options.html:

```
 $('#go-button').click(function () {
        var selectedCategories = GetSelectedCategories();
        chrome.storage.local.set({ 'selectedCategories': selectedCategories }, function () {
            console.log('this function is called!');
            chrome.storage.local.get('selectedCategories', function (result) {
                console.log('local.get result: ' + result.selectedCategories);
            })
            //window.close();
        });
    });
```

`seceltedCategories` var is fine - I've checked in console. Means, `GetSelectedCategories()` method works properly.

But `console.log('local.get result: ' + result.selectedCategories);` never get called!

`console.log('this function is called!');` starts to invoke after **second** click on appropriate button. Does it mean that I CAN NOT use options.js to access `storage.local`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="options.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="listOfCategories_form" />
  <button id="go-button">Go!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I need this categories to my content-script.

Comment: And what kind of data is returned from `GetSelectedCategories`? Is it JSON-friendly?

Comment: @Xan just 1-dimensional array of strings, like `[ 'category1', 'category2' ]`.

Comment: Quick sanity check: what kind of element is `#go-button`? Is it inside a form?

Comment: @Xan haha. `<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="options.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="listOfCategories_form" />
    <button id="go-button">Go!</button>
</body>
</html>` But I use jQuery to select this button by id. Why should I put it into form?

Comment: I was just checking if it's actually [acting as a submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39769596/934239). Doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: `src="/bower_components/jq...` may be a typo which could cause failure. It may be intended to be `src="/browser_components/jq...` However, if so, i would expect something different than what you have reported.

Comment: Please [edit] to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] duplicating the problem. Usually, include a *manifest.json*, some of the background, content, and popup scripts and HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

`FORM` is not a [void element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements) so writing `/>` at the end of its start tag doesn't close it:

> Start tags consist of the following parts, in exactly the following order:
>
> - A "<" character.
> - The element’s tag name.
> - Optionally, one or more attributes, each of which must be preceded by one or more space characters.
> - Optionally, one or more space characters.
> - Optionally, a "/" character, which **may be present only if the element is a void element.**
> - A ">" character.

The `BUTTON` element is actually inside the form as you can see in the element inspector and thus submits the form on click, reloading the document as you can see in the devtools network panel.

Solutions:

- Prevent the default event action by using `return false` in the click handler: jQuery translates it into `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`.
- Use `type="button"` attribute: `<button type="button" id="go-button">Go!</button>`